# Diffrerence between: Azure service client and device client

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, cloud, iot

I am little confuse about service client & device client library. Can anyone clear my doubt on this.

Issue: I am not able to receive data when i send it through deviceClient but same code works when i send it using service client. Now, serviceClient library is not support on xamarin platform.

Also, Is there any different between sending *data and message* to iot hub. Or both are same.

Data = telemetry data

Message = message to device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, Is there any different between sending data and message to iot
>   hub. Or both are same.

[Service client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/csharp/service#features) sends messages to your devices, while [device client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/csharp/device#features) sends event data to Azure IoT service.

> Issue: I am not able to receive data when i send it through
>   deviceClient but same code works when i send it using service client.
>   Now, serviceClient library is not support on xamarin platform.

So, in this issue, who receives data, IoT device or IoT Hub based service?

There are some official samples you can reference:

- [UWPSample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/csharp/service/Samples/UWPSample) sends messages to the IoT device.
- [DeviceClientAmqpSample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/csharp/device/samples/DeviceClientAmqpSample) sends messages to Azure IoT Hub.